# "line-based text data: text/html"

Tags: http, networking, browser, wireshark

I was checking the network response by a server in wireshark. I was wondering about a field line-based text data: "text/html".
what this the use of this line and why server send this information.

Comment: I think you might be better of putting this up somewhere like Serverfault. However, that seems to me like the server headers that stipulate the content transferred to be of type text/html . This is done so the receiving application knows how to deal with the data.

Answer (score 2):

It's the [MIME media types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) (MIME types, for short) are standardized names that describe the contents of a message entity body (e.g., `text/html`, `image/jpeg`).  For more information, you could check http://www.http-guide.com/en. MIME type is part of the http protocol.